# How fresh are index statistics in Azure Search?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I have to delete old documents to make room for new ones by a script that checks the index stats to warn when I'm reaching the storage limits. The problem I'm finding is that even after I delete 100k documents, the storage size in bytes is the same in subsequent calls to get index stats.

What should I expect with the freshness of the index stats, and if I'm not able to get an accurate result, how could I go about pruning old items from the index when needed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to Eugene's comments, there are two aspects to your question:

1. As Eugene said, we update stats approximately every minute.
2. After you add/update/delete documents we don't immediately free up space. So even if you wait a minute for stats to update, you might still see storage usage not decreasing. Periodically we run a merge background process that combines and compacts different parts of the index, which is when space is freed up. There are several factors that control when this happens (timing, update/query pressure, etc.) so it's not something you can predict entirely from outside.

Perhaps the easiest way to approach this is to delete a chunk and poll the stats once a minute until you see a decrease in size.

Answer (score 0):

Index stats are updated about once every minute. 
HTH,
Eugene

Comment: Do you have some url reference?

Comment: No URL, but I work on Azure Search team - forgot to mention that in the original response :)